# Plotting results in apache spark on-line

Tags: apache-spark, plot, spark-streaming

I want to do some prediction on a streaming data set in Apache Spark. I would like to know that is there any possibility to plot the result on-line in such a way that, when the prediction result changes, the plot also changes in real time way.
I also need to have on-line plots for my data set that accumulating in streaming way. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : https://plot.ly/?utm_source=blendoco&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dashboards. About having it updated directly in real time you can insert the data in a db and refresh with a query from the db. Another way is to use the available streaming api https://plot.ly/streaming/ (this are not for free). Seem to be possible even without the above mentioned streaming api check here https://community.plot.ly/t/real-time-without-streaming-api/3306 (there is an example on codepen.io as well in the link before)
I forgot to mention that you have the possibility to use grafana as well : https://grafana.com/